# MySQL Trigger: update record in one table where record in the same row match select query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

new to MySQL and databases and need some help. 
I have the tables:

**appointment**

- appointment_id int PK , <-
- patient_id int ,
- doctor_id int , <-
- appointment_time DateTime.

**queue**

- appointment_id int PK, <-
- actual_time DateTime.

**queue_summary**

- date datetime ,
- doctor_id int PK ,   <-
- num_of_patients int. <-

I need to write a trigger that will update the num_of_patients by adding +1 to the record in the row that the doctor_id in the queue_summary is overlapping with the new row inserted into `queue` that corresponds to the appointment (to extract the doctor_id).

ex. in case of insertion to `queue`:

[image: insertion to queue table]

appointment table status:

[image]

need to update:

[image: updating record]

I wrote the following select query to extract the doctor_id that was affected by the insertion/deletion to queue:

```
 select appointment.doctor_id
            from appointment as a 
            join queue as q 
            on a.appointment_id = q.appointment_id
            where new.appointment_id = a.appointment_id;
```

and I tried to write the trigger as followed:

```
delimiter // 

CREATE TRIGGER tr_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON queue
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN

          set queue_summary.num_of_patients = queue_summary.num_of_patients+1
          where queue_summary.doctor_id = (
          select appointment.doctor_id
            from appointment as a 
            join queue as q 
            on a.appointment_id = q.appointment_id
            where new.appointment_id = a.appointment_id
        )
       END;//
 delimiter ;
```

But with no luck... 
I know I have some syntax error in the `where` part but I can't manage it to work... 
please advise,
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SET command inside triggers can only be used on NEW var, which points to the row that is being processed. To update another table, you need to issue a normal UPDATE command:

```
delimiter // 

CREATE TRIGGER tr_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON queue
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN

          update queue_summary
          set queue_summary.num_of_patients = queue_summary.num_of_patients+1
          where queue_summary.doctor_id = (
          select appointment.doctor_id
            from appointment as a 
            join queue as q 
            on a.appointment_id = q.appointment_id
            where new.appointment_id = a.appointment_id
        )
       END;//
 delimiter ;
```

Thats the reason why appers a syntax error on where, it's because mysql set command wont expect it there, SET only accepts var name and value.